# Android:versionCode в манифесте

Tags: android, java

Чтобы выложить приложение на плеймаркет, нужно чтобы android:versionCode был равен 1. И после каждой новой версии приложения увеличивать этот параметр на единицу. Но как-то так получилось, что сейчас у меня android:versionCode="6", хотя первой версии приложения еще не было и оно не выкладывалось на плеймаркет, а понижать этот параметр нельзя, насколько я понял. Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Чтобы выложить приложение на плеймаркет, нужно чтобы android:versionCode был равен 1.

Нет, не нужно.

> И после каждой новой версии приложения увеличивать этот параметр на единицу.

Тоже нет, важно лишь, чтобы новое значение было больше предыдущего.

> Но как-то так получилось, что сейчас у меня android:versionCode="6", хотя первой версии приложения еще не было и оно не выкладывалось на плеймаркет, а понижать этот параметр нельзя, насколько я понял.

Гм. Возможно я чего-то не понимаю, но если приложение ещё не публиковалось, то что мешает руками поменять `android:versionCode` в AndroidManifest.xml?

> Как быть?

Полагаю, публиковать приложение.

Comment: при попытке уменьшить это значение приложение даже не компилируется. Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]

Comment: Не "не компилируется" а не устанавливается. Удалите прежде приложение с устройства, либо выполните `adb uninstall app_package_name`.